# Are questions purely related to IPA transcription's usage on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope

For instance, in this question:

> For the IPA translation of a whole sentence, does it matter in terms of readability if it only has a pair of brackets encompassing the whole transcription?
>
> For instance the transcription for "as soon as possible" would appear like this
>
> */əz sun əz ˈpɑsəbəl/*
>
> instead of
>
> */əz/ /sun/ /əz/ /ˈpɑsəbəl/*

I'm asking something that is rather related to how to show IPA transcriptions so that anyone can read it without any troubles.

Also, I've seen a couple of questions asking whether it's ok to use IPA transcriptions when learning a foreign language, so this question might a follow-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question in the quoted section of your answer is not related to language learning; it is purely about the technicalities of phonemic transcription, which may be on topic on [Linguistics Stack Exchange](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

As it currently stands, the question would not be on topic here.